# How to make sed or by using another command to reprint a found string?

Tags: command-line, sed

I have a string like: `testfsdfsdftestfsdkflsdtestsdfsdfsdf`

I am wondering how to separate the string so that `testfsdfsdf` appears on the first line, `testfsdkflsd` will appear on the second line, etc. like this:

```
testfsdfsdf
testfsdkflsd
testsdfsdfsdf
```

I tried using `sed` to find `test` and anything after it with `sed 's/test.*/` but I am wondering how to reprint `test.*` again. From what I know with `sed`, you can use it to find a particular string and then replace it with something else. So essentially, I wanted to try something like `sed 's/test.*/[reprint test.* here]\n/g'`, but if I do `sed 's/test.*/test.*\n/g'`, it just outputs `test.*`. Is there any way I can reprint the string found with `sed`, or can this be done with another command?

I also tried sed `'s/\(test.*\)test/\1\ntest/g'`, which works if there are only two instances of `test[random characters]`, but not three or more. With the string `testfsdfsdftestfsdkflsdtestsdfsdfsdf`, it only prints:

```
testfsdfsdftestfsdkflsd
testsdfsdfsdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. The sed command you want is

```
sed 's/test/\ntest/g'
```

It prepends a newline character to each `test`.

Now, although GNU sed and possibly others do it, the interpretation of `\n` as a newline is not specified by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03).
To make the command portable, a literal, escaped newline is required,

```
sed 's/test/\
test/g'
```

You will notice, however, that if `test` is the very first four characters
of the line, as is the case with your example, that will create an empty
line at the beginning of the output. If that is not to happen, we can use

```
sed 's/\(.\)test/\1\ntest/g'
```

`.` matches any character, so the existence of some character before `test` is *required*, otherwise the regex does not match. I.e., if `test` is the first string in the line, then `.` can't match anything and the substitution is not made.

And for the portable alternative,

```
sed 's/\(.\)test/\1\
test/g'
```

---

Some tests with GNU sed:

```
$ sed 's/test/\ntest/g' <<< 'testfsdfsdftestfsdkflsdtestsdfsdfsdf'

testfsdfsdf
testfsdkflsd
testsdfsdfsdf
$ sed 's/\(.\)test/\1\ntest/g' <<< 'testfsdfsdftestfsdkflsdtestsdfsdfsdf'
testfsdfsdf
testfsdkflsd
testsdfsdfsdf
```

---

> I also tried `sed 's/\(test.*\)test/\1\ntest/g'`, which works if there are only two instances of `test`, but not three or more.

That's because `.*` is greedy, i.e., it will match all it can. For example,

```
grep --color=always "b.*b" <<< abcabcabc
```

colors/matches everything from the first to the *last* `b`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I wonder, why does `sed 's/\(.\)\(test\)/\1\n\2/g'` not print an extra newline at the beginning of test?

Comment: @user1046658 You are welcome. I have updated the answer for more details, hope it is clearer now (tell me if not).